# Direct xargs output to file, using multiple arguments

Tags: xargs

Given a set of files, I need to pass 2 arguments and direct the output to a newly named file, based on either input filename.  The input list follows a defined format: S1_R1.txt, S1_R2.txt; S2_R1.txt, S2_R2.txt; S3_R1.txt, S3_R2.txt, etc. The first numeric is incremented by 1 and each has an R1 and corresponding R2.

The output file is a combination of each S#-pair and should be named respective of this, e.g. S1_interleave.txt, S3_interleave.txt, S3_interleave.txt, etc.

The following works to print to screen

find S*R*.txt -maxdepth 0 | xargs -n 2 python interleave.py

How can I utilize the input filenames for use as output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to make it at bit more fun: Let us assume the files are gzipped (as paired end reads often are) and you want the result gzipped, too:

```
parallel --xapply 'python interleave.py <(zcat {1}) <(zcat {2}) |gzip > {=1 s/_R1.txt.gz/_interleave.txt.gz/=}' ::: *R1.txt.gz ::: *R2.txt.gz
```

You need the pre-release of GNU Parallel to do this http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/snapshot/parallel-1a1c0ebe0f79c0ada18527366b1eabeccd18bdf5.tar.gz (or wait for the release 20140722).

As asked it is even simpler (but you still need the pre-release, though):

```
parallel --xapply 'python interleave.py {1} {2} > {=1 s/_R1.txt/_interleave.txt/=}' ::: *R1.txt ::: *R2.txt
```

Comment: I've tried editing to remove the gzipped files, as these are processed and filtered, in preparation for the assembler. Can you please add solution as asked? One of my corrections looked close, but only interleaved 1 line at a time from each line.